# python: keep char only if it is within this list

Tags: python, list, string

i have a list:

```
a = ['a','b','c'.........'A','B','C'.........'Z']
```

and i have string:

```
string1= 's#$%ERGdfhliisgdfjkskjdfW$JWLI3590823r'
```

i want to keep ONLY those characters in `string1` that exist in `a`

what is the most effecient way to do this? perhaps instead of having `a` be a list, i should just make it a string? like this `a='abcdefg..........ABC..Z'` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
''.join([s for s in string1 if s in a])
```

**Explanation**:

```
[s for s in string1 if s in a]
```

creates a list of all characters in string1, but only if they are also in the list a.

```
''.join([...])
```

turns it back into a string by joining it with nothing ('') in between the elements of the given list.

Comment: @I__ you should be aware that this becomes noticeably slow if `a` is sufficiently large. You should make it a set or go for the `re` method I've presented. `re` method is usually the fastest if `a` is large.

Comment: This is just.. amazing! :D

Answer (score 7):

This should be faster.

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = 's#$%ERGdfhliisgdfjkskjdfW$JWLI3590823r'
>>> a = ['E', 'i', 'W']
>>> r = re.compile('[^%s]+' % ''.join(a))
>>> print r.sub('', string1)
EiiWW
```

This is even faster than that.

```
>>> all_else = ''.join( chr(i) for i in range(256) if chr(i) not in set(a) )
>>> string1.translate(None, all_else)
'EiiWW'
```

44 microsec vs 13 microsec on my laptop.

How about that?

(Edit: turned out, translate yields the best performance.)

Answer (score 3):

[List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to the rescue!

```
wanted = ''.join(letter for letter in string1 if letter in a)
```

(Note that when passing a list comprehension to a function you can omit the brackets so that the full list isn't generated prior to being evaluated. While semantically the same as a list comprehension, this is called a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).)

Comment: If you omit the square brackets, it's a generator expression. So you should link to generator expressions instead.

Answer (score 1):

If, you are going to do this with large strings, there is a faster solution using `translate`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870520/in-python-how-do-you-filter-a-string-such-that-only-characters-in-your-list-are/870748#870748).

Answer (score 0):

@katrielalex: To spell it out:

```
import string 
string1= 's#$%ERGdfhliisgdfjkskjdfW$JWLI3590823r'

non_letters= ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256) if chr(i) not in string.letters)
print string1.translate(None,non_letters)

print 'Simpler, but possibly less correct'
print string1.translate(None, string.punctuation+string.digits+string.whitespace)
```