# With Python, what is the most efficient way to remove all char from string except a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, and -?

Tags: python, regex, string, formatting

Of note: maximum string ling will be 15 char.

Comment: ya ya, there are a lot of these questions but their doesn't seem to be a 'definitive' answer as to the 'most efficient' / best way to handle it.

Comment: @chrickso: for a string of length 15, even a naive algorithm will be plenty fast.

Comment: @chrickso: If what you're asking is "which of these several methods that I've seen is faster", you could at least enumerate the methods (which would also show you've done research). Of course, once you've done that you could time the methods yourself.

Comment: @chrickso unless you have mistaken 'efficiency' for raw speed then any solution will run efficiently, 15 chars can be processed in extremely fast time and so the efficiency doesn't really even matter. If you were to ask which solution is fastest for micro-optimization's sake, that would be a better question although micro-optimization is seldom required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare raw speed here are here's a comparison of [@wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12756204/464744), a few optimizations of it and a regex solution:

```
import re, string, timeit

clean = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]')
keep = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_-'
keep_set = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_-')
test = '$pam and_Eggs##-!'
cur_encoding_bytes = 256 # 8 for UTF-8, in Python 3 this would be different for Unicode
all_else = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(cur_encoding_bytes) if chr(i) not in keep_set) # taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588485/1219006

def clean1(s):
    return ''.join(x for x in s if x in keep)

def clean1_filter(s):
    return filter(keep.__contains__, s)

def clean1_filter_set(s):
    return filter(keep_set.__contains__, s)

def clean2(s):
    return clean.sub('', s)

def clean3(s):
    return s.translate(None, all_else)

print timeit.timeit('clean1(test)', 'from __main__ import clean1, test')
print timeit.timeit('clean1_filter(test)', 'from __main__ import clean1_filter, test')
print timeit.timeit('clean1_filter_set(test)', 'from __main__ import clean1_filter_set, test')
print timeit.timeit('clean2(test)', 'from __main__ import clean2, test')
print timeit.timeit('clean3(test)', 'from __main__ import clean3, test')
```

The output of this script is:

```
2.96962522809
1.56208783165
1.10597814849
1.59298783663
0.53834820236
```

`str.translate` is the fastest, being a specialized string method.

Comment: Turn `keep` into a `set` and it gets closer.

Comment: @Blender I made a more comprehensive set of tests, showing that regex is not the fastest(it usually isn't).

Comment: @jamylak: Thanks for the `.__contains__` function, I never knew about it. I tried a `lambda`, but it performed worse than the regular list comprehension.

Comment: @jamylak:  I never realized `filter` would return a string for a string argument.

Comment: @Blender:  `__contains__` is just the implementation of `in`.  I would not have thought to use it with `filter`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Right, I just never knew that there was a method that did this. I was using `filter(lambda x: x in keep_set`), but that was slower than my original two examples.

Comment: Oops forgot about `str.translate`

Comment: @jamylak: There should be an exclusive `str.translate`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def clean(s):
...   from string import ascii_letters, digits
...   keep = ascii_letters + digits + '_-'
...   return ''.join(x for x in s if x in keep)
... 
>>> clean('$pam and_Eggs##-!')
'pamand_Eggs-'
```