# translate with empty string

Tags: python, syntax

This is an example from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870748) that extracts only the lowercase letters. (Python 3)

```
import string
delete_table = string.maketrans(
    string.ascii_lowercase, ' ' * len(string.ascii_lowercase)
)
table = string.maketrans('', '')

"Agh#$%#%2341- -!zdrkfd".translate(table, delete_table)
```

In this case, the `' ' * len(string.ascii_lowercase)` maps lowercase letters to an blank space. So my expectation is that the all the lowercase letters will be replaced with ' ', a blank space, but this is the output:

```
'ghzdrkfd'
```

So here are my questions:

1. Why is the output different from my expectation?
2. When I look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), `translate` only takes in one argument. Why is it passed two arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have linked to the Python 3.x documentation, but if `translate()` is being used with multiple arguments then this code is probably from Python 2.x where that is valid.  Here is the [documentation](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

As you can see there, the second argument is optional and it specifies characters that should be deleted from the input string (on Python 3.x you would do this by mapping the characters to `None`).

So for `"Agh#$%#%2341- -!zdrkfd".translate(table, delete_table)`, first all characters present in `delete_table` are removed, and then a translation is performed using `table`.

Since `delete_table` is constructed using `string.maketrans()` translating all lowercase letters to space, it will be a string that contains every ASCII character except for lowercase letters:

```
>>> delete_table = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, ' '*len(string.ascii_lowercase))
>>> delete_table
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`                          {|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
>>> ''.join(c for c in map(chr, range(0, 256)) if c not in delete_table)
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

So all other characters will be removed from the string, and then the translation with `table` will not modify anything since `string.maketrans('', '')` is used.

Answer (score 0):

There's a member version of `translate()` as well as a static function. The member version with one argument works as you expect, while I believe it's the  static version you're calling above, perhaps incorrectly.

```
>>> "Agh#$%#%2341- -!zdrkfd".translate(delete_table)
'A  #$%#%2341- -!      '
```