# My output is exactly what is asking but is still incorrect... Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ok so I got this challenge:

> Given a string s, little Johnny defined the beauty of the string as
>   the sum of the beauty of the letters in it. The beauty of each letter
>   is an integer between 1 and 26, inclusive, and no two letters have the
>   same beauty. Johnny doesn't care about whether letters are uppercase
>   or lowercase, so that doesn't affect the beauty of a letter.
>   (Uppercase 'F' is exactly as beautiful as lowercase 'f', for example.)
>
> You're a student writing a report on the youth of this famous hacker.
>   You found the string that Johnny considered most beautiful. What is
>   the maximum possible beauty of this string?

Input sample:

> ABbCcc
>
> Good luck in the Facebook Hacker Cup this year!
>   Ignore punctuation, please :)
>
> Sometimes test cases are hard to make up.
>
> So I just go consult Professor Dalves

Output sample:

Print out the maximum beauty for the string. E.g.

> 152
>
> 754
>
> 491
>
> 729
>
> 646

When I test my code I get the output, but it is still says that it is partially solved... What am I missing?

This is my code:

```
import sys
from collections import Counter
accum=0
beauty=26
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    dictPrueba=Counter(test.strip().replace(" ","").lower())
    dictPrueba=Counter(dictPrueba).most_common()[::1]
    for i in range(0,len(dictPrueba)):
        accum+=dictPrueba[i][1]*beauty
        beauty-=1
    print accum
    accum=0
    beauty=26
test_cases.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I get perfect output, but it is still not being accepted as correct" by what? Either the output is perfect, or it's not. If it's perfect but it's not accepted, who/what is doing the accepting?

Comment: I think you should refer to the organizers of that challenge, rather than to SO.

Comment: its a codeeval challenge and for some reason it says it is partially solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the requested output. Your code isn't working as it should. In fact, running your code on the examples you provided, the output is:

```
152
761 #wrong
527 #wrong
741 #wrong
646
```

The obvious reason for this is that you're not ignoring punctuation as instructed. To ignore punctuation, you can use:

```
dictPrueba=Counter(''.join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", t)).lower())
```

Using this line I get the correct output.

Another suggestions is perhaps they intended you to have a constant scoring scheme for each letter across different tests (which is not the case in your code now, which gives the highest score to the most abundant letter) but I have no way of telling if this is true.

And as a side note - this line: `Counter(dictPrueba).most_common()[::1]` is redundant. `Counter(dictPrueba)` produces the same output as `dictPrueba` and the `[::1]` in the end changes nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your observation. If you could explain better the redundancy of that line of code I would appreciate it.

also I edited my code and added 
test="".join(l for l in test if l not in string.punctuation)
to remove punctuation, but the code still is partially solved

Comment: I don't see how I can explain this any further. `x=Counter(dictPrueba).most_common()[::1]` and `x=dictPrueba.most_common()` produce exactly the same `x`.

Comment: @FutoFarai It's a way to extract letters out of a string. It return a list of strings of consecutive letters found in the original string, which I later join to a single string. For other methods of extracting letters out of a string see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870520/in-python-how-do-you-filter-a-string-such-that-only-characters-in-your-list-are)

Comment: Thanks for the help and the new knowledge!